# remind someone reply a appointment time

Tags: prepositions, email

Last week I applied for a job. After the first interview, I got an email to arrange another interview with the recruiter. So I wrote an email like

```
...
Please let me know what possible meeting times would be most convenient for you?
...
```

but he did not respond. So I tried to send a reminder as below. Is there anything wrong in the letter below?

```
...
I hope this email finds you well. 
I’ll be waiting your reply schedule the interview  ? 
...
```

Comment: I doubt that the interviewer was looking for you to send him/her an email that just said "...convenient for you?". They probably wanted you to send them an email that gave them some timeframes of when would work for you. For example, I can do the interview anytime wednesday, thursday, and fridays anytime between 8am and 3pm. Then they would have replied with an exact meeting time that worked within your schedule.  That is just my opinion based on what info you provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the closest correct sentence to what you wrote is:

> I'm awaiting your reply to schedule the interview.

*Waiting* is an intransitive verb and would not take a direct object.  If you want a transitive verb, you can use *awaiting*.  You could also say *I'm waiting **for** your reply.*  Also, this is a statement of fact, not a question, so it should end in a period `.` instead of a question mark `?`.  Finally, punctuation marks like `.` and `?` should immediately follow the last word of the sentence, without any space in between (but do leave a space before the first word of the next sentence).

However, such a direct sentence may come across as rude or impatient.   I might write something more like

> I hope this finds you well.  I was wondering if you have had time yet to schedule the interview we discussed.  I look forward to meeting with you at your convenience.

Answer (score 1):

You can reply on the same mail and use :
"I hope this email finds you well. This is a gentle reminder enquiring about a convenient meeting time for the next round of the interview process."
**OR**
"I hope this email finds you well. Have you had a chance to take out some time to schedule the next round of the interview process ?"

Comment: Saying "**the** convenient meeting time" suggests that a time has already been established.  You should say "**a** convenient meeting time".   And "the next round of interview" isn't correct.  I would say "the next round of interviews" or "the next round of the interview process" or even "the next interview round".

Comment: A convenient time and the next round of the interview process look correct..  edited the answer.

Comment: Yes, that looks better.  Also, I think "take out some time" should just be "take some time".

Answer (score 1):

I might reply on the same mail and use:
"I'm resending this email in case you haven't received it.
It would be appreciated if you would reply me as soon as possible."